# UITableViewCell with xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm developing an app for iOS which use the xib files.

Usually I use Storyboard and `I don't know how to set up a UITableViewCell with xib files`. When I make a xib file with a UITableView, I see a table with some row, now I need to edit this row to write what I stored in an array.

**How can I use the xib file to design a UITableViewCell?**

I need to do a very simple table: I would to use the Basic preset for the cell to display a title.
I know that I've to connect the delegate and DataSource to the file owner for table view and I put in the file owner the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Now **how I can edit the content of the cell?**
I found on the web some guide that tells to create a xib file with a UITableViewCell and I did it, but I don't know how to work with this

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Firstly, you need to create the class for the customCell which inherits from UITableViewCell.
Now, add the properties you want to have in your customCell. In this example I added cellImage and cellLabel.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageView;
```

After that you need to link the UILabel and the UIImageView from the CustomCell to the Nib.

You need to add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    ....
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"xibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    .....
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuse";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.cellImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever"]];
    [cell.cellLabel setText = @"whatever"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: when I do below :
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
It loads the custom cell but not in your way. what is fundamental difference ?