# How do you put UI elements inside table view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an app where UI elements (Buttons, switches, segmented controllers, steppers, etc.) are inside of a table view. I am also programming in swift. How do you do this?

Comment: You can use accessoryView of a cell to add them. Moreover create sub class for UITableViewCell, where you can have all your desired controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Custom `UITableViewCell` using `Nib` (`.xib`) file. Then add UI controls and create connections within it as same as we are adding and connecting controls into `UIViewController`. You can also do it programmatically but this method is time consuming and also to add `Autolayout` through xib will be easier.

There are some tutorial available:

[Tutorial 1](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/823_Creating_a_Custom_UITableViewCell.aspx)

[Tutorial 2](https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722)

[Tutorial 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19399960/1635315)

Hope this will help you.